# How can I set 'User Defined Runtime Attributes' on story board when I use dynamic width or height?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, storyboard

simply I set a UIImageView for a user's profile, and its width is 1/4 from its superview's width. (aspect ratio is 1:1)
I want to make it like circle so, I put 75 into 'User Defined Runtime Attributes' (because its superview width is 600, and imageview width is 150, constraint equal width and multiplier is 1:4).
However, I run it, the profile image looks like diamond shape, not circle because its wide is changing depends on device width.
Does anyone have any idea or any link I can refer?